# Switch between two opened tabs in the MATLAB editor

Tags: matlab, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I have opened several files in the MATLAB editor.

If I want to go to the previously used file, it is relatively difficult to have to look for (and click on) the name of the file.

Instead, can we use a MATLAB shortcut to directly go to the previously used file within the opened files?

I am not asking about using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>page up</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>page down</kbd> to move to the neighbouring files in the editor, but instead want to go to the one which was previously in focus.

Comment: Why does CTRL+page down not work for you?

Comment: @Ander I believe this is the question: "I have files A, B and C open, I'm in file A. I switch to file C. How can I quickly toggle between A and C  (the previously used file each time), without going up and down the files one at a time using Ctrl+PgUp/Down?" Raghu: if this is correct, [edit] the question to clarify along these lines and we can re-open it.

Comment: This is not something you can do natively, you may need to write your own code which hooks into the MATLAB editor. Here is a post on closing all editor windows which you may be able to adapt and add to a shortcut: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/345583-close-all-variable-editor-windows

Answer (score -4):

You can always use Notepad++ and use 'Ctrl+Tab' there. Any changes you make will be reflected in the MATLAB editor as well.
But if you really want it to be in the MATLAB editor, right click all the files and 'Undock' them, then you can perform a normal 'Alt+Tab'.
I am not sure if there is any other way.

Comment: "Use a different application" is not an answer to the question of how to do something in the MATLAB editor... The MATLAB editor has numerous advantages over editing MATLAB code in Notepad++, there's no way that being able to tab between files would outweigh the disadvantages.

Comment: @Wolfie, I understand that using a different application is not an answer, I had just suggested an alternative of doing it if that was really needed. Nevertheless, I did give an answer on a way to do it in MATLAB.